# How to count number of rows in a spark dataframe based on a value (primary key) from another dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. Both have a column 'date' as shown below.

Structure of df1

```
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|02-01-2015|
|02-02-2015|
|02-03-2015|
+----------+
```

Structure of df2

```
+---+-------+-----+----------+
| ID|feature|value|      date|
+---+-------+-----+----------+
|  1|balance|  100|01-01-2015|
|  1|balance|  100|05-01-2015|
|  1|balance|  100|30-01-2015|
|  1|balance|  100|01-02-2015|
|  1|balance|  100|01-03-2015|
+---+-------+-----+----------+
```

I have to take each row in 'date' column from df1, compare with df2 'date' and get all rows from df2 that are less than the date in df1.

Say take first row 02-01-2015 from df1 and get all rows that are less than 02-01-2015 from df2 which should produce an output as follows

```
+---+-------+-----+----------+
| ID|feature|value|      date|
+---+-------+-----+----------+
|  1|balance|  100|01-01-2015|
+---+-------+-----+----------+
```

What is the best way to achieve this in spark-scala ? I have hundreds of millions of rows. I thought of using window function in spark but window is limitied to one dataframe.

Comment: you want to take only one row from df1 at a time or all at once?

Comment: Hi Ramesh. Yes take one row from df1 at a time and compare 'date' in df2 and get all rows from df2 whose date is less than date in df1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this gets you all results in a new dataframe:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  "02-01-2015",
  "02-02-2015",
  "02-03-2015"
).toDF("date")
  .withColumn("date", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy")))

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "balance", 100, "01-01-2015"),
  (1, "balance", 100, "05-01-2015"),
  (1, "balance", 100, "30-01-2015"),
  (1, "balance", 100, "01-02-2015"),
  (1, "balance", 100, "01-03-2015")
).toDF("ID", "feature", "value", "date")
  .withColumn("date", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy")))

df1.join(
  df2, df2("date") < df1("date"), "left"
).show()


+-------------------+---+-------+-----+-------------------+
|               date| ID|feature|value|               date|
+-------------------+---+-------+-----+-------------------+
|2015-01-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-01-01 00:00:00|
|2015-02-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-01-01 00:00:00|
|2015-02-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-01-05 00:00:00|
|2015-02-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-01-30 00:00:00|
|2015-02-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-02-01 00:00:00|
|2015-03-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-01-01 00:00:00|
|2015-03-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-01-05 00:00:00|
|2015-03-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-01-30 00:00:00|
|2015-03-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-02-01 00:00:00|
|2015-03-02 00:00:00|  1|balance|  100|2015-03-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+---+-------+-----+-------------------+
```

EDIT: 
to get the number of matchign records from df2, do :

```
 df1.join(
    df2, df2("date") < df1("date"), "left"
 )
 .groupBy(df1("date"))
 .count
 .orderBy(df1("date"))
 .show

+-------------------+-----+
|               date|count|
+-------------------+-----+
|2015-01-02 00:00:00|    1|
|2015-02-02 00:00:00|    4|
|2015-03-02 00:00:00|    5|
+-------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks Raphel. You answer works. Is there any way we can use count or aggregate functions on value column after each iteration ? Say take first row 02-01-2015 from df1 and get all rows that are less than 02-01-2015 from df2 and count the number of rows and show it as results rather than displaying the rows itself ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to compare only one row of `df1` with `df2` `date` then you should first `select` the intended row from `df1`

```
val oneRowDF1 = df1.select($"date".as("date2")).where($"date" === "02-01-2015")
```

then you should `join` with the logic you have as

```
df2.join(oneRowDF1, unix_timestamp(df2("date"), "dd-MM-yyyy") < unix_timestamp(oneRowDF1("date2"), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
    .drop("date2")
```

which should give you

```
+---+-------+-----+----------+
|ID |feature|value|date      |
+---+-------+-----+----------+
|1  |balance|100  |01-01-2015|
+---+-------+-----+----------+
```

**Updated**

Joins are expensive as it requires shuffling of data between executors of different nodes.

You can simply use filter function as below

```
val oneRowDF1 = df1.select(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy").as("date2")).where($"date" === "02-01-2015")

df2.filter(unix_timestamp($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy") < oneRowDF1.take(1)(0)(0))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. Appreciate your help. Literally I have millions of rows in df1 and a billion rows in df2 which means I have to do join operation million times and Join is a very expensive operation as you might know. Is there any built-in better spark approaches like sliding windows ?

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. It works. I will run with and without join on the full dataset and post the metrics. Appreciate your help